# I want to know that my whatsapp picture message sent or not?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have sent a picture message to wrong person in whatsapp, single (-/)tick shown on picture message, immediately i switched off the mobile, and after few minutes, switched on the mobile, still it shows single tick on the message, i immediately deleted the message, removed from whatsapp chat, and blocked his whatsapp accout. So, i want to ask yout that, is the wrong message will be deliverd to the person or not?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably yes, single tick means the message is received at server and is awaiting to be delivered to the person you sent it to. (Double tick means the message is delivered, and the blue tick means it's read)

I'm afraid to tell you, the image has been sent, and the person will receive it once he connects to the internet. But as you have deleted the image from your phone you won't get the second tick and the blue tick for that matter, and you'll never know when the person actually saw the image.